# How to properly add inline label and logarithmic colour scale on 2D lien plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a 2Dline plot with inline labels and logarithmic color bar scale.
So far, I plot the inline label, but the problem is each line showing more than one label.

Here is my script:

```
num=np.linspace(2, 10, 15)
en=[0.000001,0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
dis=[]
for i in en:
    for j in num:
        dist=0.48*j -0.33*np.log10(i)  -1.4
        r=10**dist
        dis.append(r)
dd=np.array(dis)
AA=dd.reshape(10, 15)
D=pd.DataFrame(AA)
D=np.transpose(D)
m=pd.DataFrame(num)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.plot(m[0], D[0], label='$0.000001{J/m^3}$',color='b', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid')
labelLines(plt.gca().get_lines(), zorder=2, align=True, fontsize=14)
ax.plot(m[0], D[1], label='$0.00001$',color='b', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.8)
labelLines(plt.gca().get_lines(), zorder=2, align=True, fontsize=14)
ax.plot(m[0], D[2],label='$0.0001$',color='b', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.6)
labelLines(plt.gca().get_lines(), zorder=2, align=True, fontsize=14)
ax.plot(m[0], D[3],label='$0.001$',color='b', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.4)
labelLines(plt.gca().get_lines(), zorder=2, align=True, fontsize=14)
ax.plot(m[0], D[4],label='$0.01$',color='b', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.4)
ax.plot(m[0], D[5],label='$0.1$',color='r', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.2)
ax.plot(m[0], D[6], label='$1$',color='r', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.4)
ax.plot(m[0], D[7], label='$10$',color='r', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.6)
ax.plot(m[0], D[8], label='$100$',color='r', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.8)
ax.plot(m[0], D[9],  label='$01000$',color='r', lw=2.5, linestyle='solid')
#ax.legend(inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(2, 10)
ax.set_ylim(1, 20000)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=14)

for axis in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(2)
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get so far

[image]

Comment: Do you want the color of each line to change logarithmically? If so you could perhaps use hexstring to choose the color you want.

Comment: @Albertbayazidi each line has a represent a constant value that is a multiple of 10. So I need to represent the line value as a logarithmic color bar. Please see modified question for expected result.